# How do I get this loop to grab from every worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm grabbing data in columns A-K from each worksheet and putting it into a single sheet. My code as it stands is grabbing the first sheet correctly, but it isn't getting anything after that. I honestly have no idea why.

Here is my code as it stands now:

```
Sub compile()

Dim srcRange, destRange As Range
Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
Dim wksheet_number, lastRow As Long

wksheet_number = 1

For Each wkSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If wksheet_number > 1 Then

        lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wksheet_number).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set srcRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wksheet_number).Range("A2:K" & lastRow)
        Set destRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")

        If destRange.Value = "" Then

            srcRange.copy destRange

        Else

            Set destRange = srcRange.End(xlDown)
            Set destRange = srcRange.Offset(1, 0)
            'destRange.Select

            srcRange.copy destRange

        End If

        wksheet_number = wksheet_number + 1

    Else

        wksheet_number = wksheet_number + 1

    End If

Next wkSheet


End Sub
```

Apologies for the lack commenting, it is something I should probably add next time. So anyone know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the following corrections to your code:

```
Set destRange = destRange.End(xlDown)
Set destRange = destRange.Offset(1, 0)
```

You were referring to `srcRange` instead of `destRange`, so it was just over-copying the same range (in the other worksheets).

Comment: I feel like a dumbass... Thank you Andy

Comment: Good ;) Don't worry, it's an easy mistake to make, and tricky to find when it doesn't cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Andy G. Here is an alternative, shorter version of your procedure. Since you are looping through each worksheet in the workbook, the use of the `wksheet_number` variable is unnecessary. You can just use the `wkSheet` object directly in each iteration of the loop.

```
Sub compile()

    Dim srcRange, destRange As Range
    Dim wkSheet, sheetDestination As Worksheet
    Dim columnCount, lastRow As Long

    rowCount = 2 'Starting at A2

    Set sheetDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'Also could use the name like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyReport")

    For Each wkSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If Not wkSheet = sheetDestination Then

            lastRow = wkSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set srcRange = wkSheet.Range("A2:K" & lastRow)
            Set destRange = sheetDestination.Range("A" & rowCount)

            srcRange.Copy destRange

            rowCount = rowCount + lastRow + 1

        End If

    Next wkSheet


    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this first and it was giving me some problems, but at the time I'd forgotten to put on the .worksheets on "ThisWorkBook". This definitely is cleaner though. Thanks!